# Detecting passwords in code repos

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow

I'm a newbie to ML trying to understand if its feasible to train a network to detect inadvertent inclusion of passwords in code repositories. One way to do this is to tokenize the code within a repo and then use heuristics for an "entropy estimate" for each token through a Shannon entropy variant known as "N-gram entropy"

Is it feasible to do this with a deep network or a linear model (and which would be better)  where the input would be a token or tuples of tokens and output for the classifier would be a binary "yes" or "no" (for the tuple containing / not containing a password)

How large the training set would need to be? 
Can someone give me some pointers on how to model this or some code that could serve as a starting point? For example I started looking at the tensorflow examples related to language processing eg. word embeddings, noise contrastive training could any of this be relevant?

ML Newbie

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just search through repos with a simple rexexp like `pass.*[= :].*[a-zA-Z0-9]/i`? That would catch 99% of cases...

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @naught101, a simple regular expression is likely to be very performant.

Another approach could be to look at the strings in the code (you can isolate them easily since they will often be between quotes) that matches [some of the most common passwords](http://www.passwordrandom.com/most-popular-passwords) (or that are close enough to these, with respect to a [string metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric))